# bash script - iterate over two (or more) ranges simultaneously in for loop

Tags: bash

I know that is possible to iterate over few arrays in `bash` for loop or any command like echo ([Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)).

```
for i in {1..4} {a..d}
    echo $i

# or
echo {1..4} {a..d}

# output: 1 2 3 4 a b c d
```

But is it possible to iterate over arrays simultaneously to get result like:

```
# output: 1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d
```

For example I need to ssh to three range of servers with names like server-a1.com, server-b1.com, server-c1.com and need to perform action on all firsts, than on all seconds and so on.

Comment: I would phrase `1 a 2 b 3 c` as `only first of the first, only second of the second and so on` and not `all the firsts, then on all seconds and so on`

Answer (score 2):

You can generate all the combinations with

```
echo {1..4}{a..d}
```

If you select each fifth, you'll get what you wanted:

```
all=({1..4}{a..d})
for (( i=0 ; i<${#all[@]} ; i++ )) ; do
    (( !(i % 5) )) && echo ${all[i]}
done
```

Comment: Innovative & cool ;) Is it possible to generalize it with a computed value instead of 5 so that the script will work for `{1..5}{a..e}`,`{1..6}{a..f}` and so on?

Comment: @sjsam: If both lists are of the same size, you can use size + 1,or `bc <<< "1+sqrt(${#all[@]})"`.

Comment: Thank you and appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

sure

```
 for i in {1..4} ; do
    for j in {a..d} ; do
       echo ssh  user@server-${i}${j}.com 'cmd'
    done
 done
```

**output**

```
ssh user@server-1a.com cmd
ssh user@server-1b.com cmd
ssh user@server-1c.com cmd
ssh user@server-1d.com cmd
ssh user@server-2a.com cmd
ssh user@server-2b.com cmd
ssh user@server-2c.com cmd
. . .
```

Of course, you get to make your own `ssh` cmdline using the `${i}` and `${j}` when needed.

I have used `echo ssh ...` to be a placeholder for your real processes.

IHTH

Comment: That's not how I interpreted the last line of the question above : *"For example I need to ssh to three range of servers with names like server-a1.com, server-b1.com, server-c1.com and need to perform action on all firsts, than on all seconds and so on."*. As the O.P. never responded to any of the provided answers, I didn't see any reason to take this further. Feel free to write your own answer ;-) Good luck to all!

Comment: But yes, I got the order o `a1` vs `1a` wrong. It is obvious how to fix that, so I'll leave it as is. Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want:

```
a=( {1..4} )
b=( {a..d} )
for (( i=0; i<${#a[@]}; i++ )); do
    echo -n "${a[i]} ${b[i]} "
done
```

The range expansion is put into two arrays. The index of the first array are used to refer to both arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
a=({1..4})    b=({a..d})    i=0                ### Initial values

for ((i=0; i<4; i++ )) ; do                    ### Loop over elements
      printf '%s %s    ' "${a[i]}" "${b[i]}"   ### Print pairs of values.
done
echo
```

---

```
$ ./script.sh
1 a    2 b    3 c    4 d
```